# Database First DBContext works locally but not when deployed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I deployed a webapi project to azure that connects to a database via a DbContext. Everything works locally but when I deploy I am hit with an error anytime I make a request that will need to access my DbContext.

I open a connection as follows:

```
 public ProductRepo(ProdStoreEntities context)
        {
            dbContext = context;
            dbContext.Database.Connection.Open();
        }
```

My web.config is as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-CatalogAPI-20160227031830.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-CatalogAPI-20160227031830;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ProdStoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DbCache.csdl|res://*/DbCache.ssdl|res://*/DbCache.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=ProdStore;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I would have thought that everything would be handled for me since I am using a DbContext but when I deploy and attempt to make a get request that would require a database query I recieve the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Any ideas on why this might be happening? I haven't done anything special when publishing, I literally right click my class libray and hit publish. I initally generated the DbContext via a database first approach if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be from a few things.

Check that you are running Localdb on your deployment server

Secondly, check that the database has been intialized on the deployed server.

Thirdly, are you able to to login to the database via management studio via the credentials you're providing - Make sure your user details has the privileges on the deployed server to access the database

Comment: I use windows authentication to log into the database locally. But I don't want my deployed web service to access my local database. I want a copy of my database to be published along side my web api project. I thought this would be automatic since I am using DbContext? Is my assumption incorrect?

Comment: DbContext will take care of the database setup, but it first needs to be able to connect to somewhere where it can create a database. As Chimera below points out, your connection string points to a local database. You need to specify a connection string to where your deployed db will be hosted and then create an empty DB or use migrations etc. When your DbContext will take care of everything else.

Comment: So I create an empty database on azure, get its connection string and put it in the settings tab when I publish? My DbContext will then create a copy of my local database and put it in the azure environment? Or will I have to manually configure the azure database to match my local one?

Comment: Creating an empty database on azure, getting its connection and putting it in the settings tab will work. DbContext should do the rest. There will be no data in there obviously, unless you have seeded it. Could you update your question and post the Dbcontext code and your models?

Comment: I created an empty database and added its connection strings into my publish tab and it seems to work somewhat. My error changed and now I get a 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.'

In the inner exception I see 'Invalid object name 'dbo.Product''. So I assume it is not correctly copying my database design?

Comment: You're correct. Can you post your DB context and models please?

Comment: I would but I don't know which DB context code you're referring to? And you want to see my database model?

Comment: The one named dbcontext

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your connection string says that it is a local database.
what you have to do is create a database in Azure, when you have done that you can actually see a connection string to that database, that connection string needs to replace your current connection string where you have your (local) db